# how to delay loading the page in route AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, authorization

I would like to before the advent of the home page if the user is not logged in is to move it to the login page.

At this moment Main page appears (half a second) and then loads the login page.

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate"])

.constant('ACCESS_LEVELS', {
    guest: 1,
    user: 2,
    admin: 3
});


app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", "ACCESS_LEVELS", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, ACCESS_LEVELS) {

    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            template: "",
            access_level: ACCESS_LEVELS.user
        });
}]);

app.run(["$rootScope", "$window", "LoginService", function($rootScope, $window, LoginService) {

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(evt, next, curr) {

        if(next.access_level !== undefined) {
            LoginService.checkSession().then(function(response) {
                $rootScope.isLoggedIn = response;
                if(!response)  {
                    $window.location.href = '/login.html';
                }
            }, function(error) {
                $rootScope.isLoggedIn = error;
            });
        }
 })
}]);
```

Is there a way to angular done without flash home page? 
regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ‘resolve’ property of the routeProvider.

From the docs:

> resolve - An optional map of dependencies which should be >injected into the controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait >for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

So your routeProvider could look as follows, with the session promise specified as a dependency of your home route. You would then need to inject the session into the home controller.

```
 $routeProvider
   .when("/", {
     template: "",
     access_level: ACCESS_LEVELS.user,
     controller: ‘homeCtrl’,
     resolve: {
       session: function(LoginService) {
         return LoginService.checkSession();
       }
     }
   });
```

A good blog post: http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/show-route-only-after-all-promises-are-resolved

Answer (score 0):

My current code:

in main app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "ngResource"])

.constant('ACCESS_LEVELS', {
    guest: 1,
    user: 2,
    admin: 3
});


besecure.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", "ACCESS_LEVELS", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, ACCESS_LEVELS) {

    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            template: "",
            label: "Home",
            access_level: ACCESS_LEVELS.user,
            resolve: {
                session: function(LoginService) {
                    return LoginService.checkSession();
                }
            }

        });
}]);

app.run(["$rootScope", "$window", "$location", "LoginService", function($rootScope, $window, $location, LoginService) {

    $rootScope.loadingView = false;

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(evt, curr, prev) {
        if(curr.access_level !== undefined) {
            if(curr.$$route && curr.$$route.resolve) {
                $rootScope.loadingView = true;
            } else {
                $window.location.href = '/login.html';
            }
        }
    })
}]);
```

Service:

```
app.factory("LoginService", function($resource, $q) {
    var LoginService,
        Login = $resource("/auth/login");
LoginService = {
        checkSession: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            Login.get().$promise.then(function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.result);
            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject(false);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
};

    return LoginService;
});
```

Service is OK. 
and not work redirecting